# Making swapfile for t1.micro Amazon EC2 instance with Amazon Linux

Tags: swap, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I'm using `t1.micro` EC2 instance with Amazon Linux. Since the micro instance has limited RAM (589MB RAM in total), it is insufficient for many operations such as installing & compiling Python packages. Some tutorials suggest me to make use of a Swap file to increase performance, as follow:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /tmp/swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /tmp/swapfile
sudo mkswap /tmp/swapfile
sudo swapon /tmp/swapfile
```

and remove it by:

```
sudo swapoff /tmp/swapfile
sudo rm /tmp/swapfile
```

I think this will increase Disk I/O, but it will benefit the overall performance. Should I enable a large swap file when the OS is booted up & leave it always active? If yes, how to achieve this?

FYI: the output of the `free -m` command is as follow:

```
[ec2-user@myhostname ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           589        340        249          0         13         97
-/+ buffers/cache:        229        360
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create a swap space by:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/swapfile bs=1M count=1024 
    (# bs*count = file size)

sudo mkswap /tmp/swapfile

sudo chmod 600 /tmp/swapfile
    (# for security reasons)

sudo swapon /tmp/swapfile

free -h
```

**Remove by:**

```
swapoff /tmp/swapfile

rm -f /tmp/swapfile
```

Comment: The main question is, should I do so? I have already listed out how to make swap file in my question.

Comment: Yes,if you need more space to run programs

Comment: Apart from increased Disk I/O, is there any drawbacks by doing so?

Comment: The only way is to switch to an instance with more ram.